# Where is the <import> tag in Nant?

Tags: c#, nant

I want to import another build file into my current project so I can put all common properties in one place.

In ant you can simply use:

```
<import file="c:\tools\commonProperties.include" />
```

How to achieve that in NAnt?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `include` Task.

[NAnt: include task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/include.html)

```
<include buildfile="GetProjectVersion.include" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The properties defined on the included file are not valid on the main build file.

Comment: This should definitely work. Make sure you're not having an issue with the `overwrite` attribute of the properties.

Comment: One thing: The properties in the included file need to be direct child nodes of the `project` node.